# Is it possible to integrate vscode as extension in jupyterhub?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyterhub

I am trying to get VScode as extension in my jupyterhub as we have terminal, python console etc.
so that any user can click on vscode icon and get the data copied to his/her local vscode setup on laptop/computer.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what you really want but you can connect from your local VSCode to remote JupyterHub server using API token: https://blog.jupyter.org/connect-to-a-jupyterhub-from-visual-studio-code-ed7ed3a31bcb